# Is there a "simple" way to have ld output demangled funtion names?

Tags: c++, c++-faq

I find very frustrating to have to fix C++ errors happening at linkage time (especially undefined reference errors) due to the fact that all the function names are mangled. An example of mangled name:

```
_ZNK5boost7archive6detail11oserializerINS0_13text_oarchiveEN9galandria8UniverseEE16save_object_dataERNS1_14basic_oarchiveEPKv
```

It is so hard to read, and finding the actual function is even harder.

Is there a way to convince `ld` to output demangled names?

Comment: If you de-mangle function names then you are, effectively, breaking C++ ... one of its key features is the ability to have different overloads for functions, which relies on name-mangling.

Comment: Have you tried `c++filt`?

Comment: I mean, in the error messages. Having to find what is _ZNK5boost7archive6detail11oserializerINS0_13text_oarchiveEN9galandria8UniverseEE16save_object_dataERNS1_14basic_oarchiveEPKv can become quite difficult.

Comment: How about adding `--demangle`? That *might* help.

Comment: Can you provide a sample output from your linker (maybe 10-20 lines)?

Comment: [ld documentation on --demangle](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html): `These options control whether to demangle symbol names in error messages and other output.`

Comment: GCC demangles function names automatically, [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60264d3655dc4f75).

Comment: What compiler, settings etc?

Comment: @AdrianMole C++ mangles function names in object (ELF) files, but it is possible to demangle them along with its arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ld` (The GNU Linker) is able to demangle C++ function names. `ld` documentation on demangling from it's `man` page: (available [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) online)

```
       --demangle[=style]
       --no-demangle
           These options control whether to demangle symbol names in error
           messages and other output.  When the linker is told to demangle,
           it tries to present symbol names in a readable fashion: it strips
           leading underscores if they are used by the object file format,
           and converts C++ mangled symbol names into user readable names.
           Different compilers have different mangling styles.  The optional
           demangling style argument can be used to choose an appropriate
           demangling style for your compiler.  The linker will demangle by
           default unless the environment variable COLLECT_NO_DEMANGLE is
           set.  These options may be used to override the default.
```

Let's see an example:

```cpp
void foo();
void foo(int);
int main() {
    foo();
    foo(5);
}
```

This is a simple valid code. This will compile but fail to link successfully because there is no implementation of `foo()` and `foo(int)` here. Now we'll compile it with the following command:

```sh
g++ main.cpp -c -o main.o
```

It will compile successfully. Now let's try to link it with demangling disabled with the following command:

```sh
g++ main.o -Wl,--no-demangle
```

It should show linking errors with some weird mangled name like this:

```
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `_Z3foov'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `_Z3fooi'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[See live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfda2e26982ef886)

Now let's try to link with demangling enabled with the following command:

```sh
g++ main.o -Wl,--demangle
```

We'll get errors with demangled function names with their arguments like this:

```
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `foo()'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `foo(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[See live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42ec45e9a95a06c3)

Here `-Wl` means arguments to linker.

As far as I know, `g++` enables demangling automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I deal with these problems in two ways:

1. The `c++filt` command demangles things.
2. Sometimes compiling with clang rather than gcc, or vice versa, can give insight on compilation issues.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure if it's possible to get demangled output from the linker directly :-(

Comment: Yes. I agree. Just i find c++filt to be too manual. I will have liked to have ld able to demangle the error messages but I have been unable to get that.

Comment: Linker can't do that, those names is what it gets as input from ELF file

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Why? It is true that linker gets a mangled name, but it do some processing to demangle it.

Comment: @AkibAzmain not all implementations.  keyword is that it tries, if compiler is known and compatible, to give readable output. For linking it's not required.That's reason for mangling - to have unique names for all overloaded function and nested variables\members, so linker can just associate a string to string. ELF format is language agnostic and linking performed on assumption that two equal symbol with global linkage in different units refer to same entity.